# What is this kind of switch called?

Tags: switches

Please take a look at this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HKQTuVD2ac and tell me what's the LITTLE BLACK switch called where he changes the challenges (1 to 10) with. I guess technically it's a number decoder but I'd like to know the name of the design of the switch as shown in the video.

image link: http://www.abload.de/img/unbenannt9sz1b.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A datasheet for a similar switch is shown [here.](http://www.ia.omron.com/data_pdf/data_sheet/a7d_a7dp_ds_csm27.pdf)

This datasheet refers to the switch as a "push operated" type of "thumbwheel switch."

You may also hear this called a BCD switch, since the selected number (0-9) is provided, electrically, as four bits coded in [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) (Binary Coded Decimal) format.  If the switch includes all 16 of the four bit values (0-F) is may be referred to as a HEX switch.

Comment: thanks for that! thumbwheel switch was the term i was looking for.